# How to remove the tax on cart when tax setting is set to display catalog prices including tax

Tags: magento-1.8, tax, tax-class

I am Stuck in very weird situation where I want to remove the tax that is displayed in the cart when tax setting is set to display catalog prices including tax.
I tried to remove this by setting taxclassID to 0 but didnot get any result please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following code that is used to remove any type of tax irrespective of inclusive or exclusive

```
$inc=$address->getGrandTotal();
                            $tax=$address->getTaxAmount();
                            $exc_tax = $address->getGrandTotal() - $address->getTaxAmount();
                            $address->setSubtotalInclTax($exc_tax);
                            $product->setPrice($exc_tax);
                            $product->setTaxClassId(0);
                            $finalPrice=$exc_tax;
```

I hope this will help you all